# What is the purpose of the $before and $after arguments on the the_title() function?

Tags: templates

I'm new to WordPress and currently using _s as a base theme to create my own. I've noticed that post/page titles are usually inserted like this:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

I was wondering what the advantage of the above approach is compared to doing it like this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

To me the first approach seems more complicated and harder to maintain than the second, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: one advantage would be that an empty title would also not output the 'before' and 'after' tags...

Comment: @Michael: Right, I didn't think of that but it's probably the reason why they do it that way. If you post this as an answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are just fine. Before and after parameters are not there for just only passing htags into it. you can have any type of strings, image or html set to before and after parameters.

This is WordPress way and they have set the standards just like any other CMS or Framework. so its always better to follow these standards.

Secondly: i've not seen source of `the_title` yet. maybe this helps in generating error free html output and even they may validate and filter passed texts.

Lastly in my opinion it looks more professional way of coding to me.